# How can I rewrite this sentence

Tags: meaning

In a scientific context I want to say that if there are devices in the idle mode, there shouldn't be any overloaded device. I have written this sentence like this:

> There is no overloaded device in the network while other devices are
> in the idle mode

but it sounds not good and doesn't convey the meaning I intend. How can I correct this sentence?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say. Obviously, if (all) devices are in "idle" mode, none of them can be "overloaded". What's the point of the word ***other*** here?

Comment: oic - *no device can be overloaded if any other device is in idle mode*. That seems like a "back-to-front" way of saying that *no device will enter idle mode if any other device is overloaded.* But maybe at the margin there's a nuance of difference between my phrasing and yours (what happens to a device that was validly placed in idle mode, **after which** some other device became overloaded?).

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Imagine we have several devices. some of them may have a lot of tasks to perform, but some of them may be idle. I want to say that if there is a device which has a lot of tasks to do (is overloaded), there should not be a device in idle mode. (I want to do load balancing and move some of the tasks from overloaded device to idle device). I hope this explanation makes my purpose more clear

Comment: Yes, I do understand what you mean. But it wasn't entirely clear to me initially, and I *think* that's because to me the "natural" way of specifying this "system constraint" is to say that "No device can enter the 'idle' state if any other device is overloaded" (rather than your version, which amounts to "No device can be overloaded if any devices are idle"). It's like the difference between *No worker can leave while any other workers are busy* and *No workers can be busy if any workers have left.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer by chasly is reasonable. However, it may not say what you intend. Here is a different interpretation of what you may mean.

> None of the devices can become overloaded if at least one is in idle mode.

The difference between my proposal and chasly's is not one of grammar or style but of meaning.

What do you **WANT TO SAY**?

My experience has been that whenever I am dissatisfied with the sound of a sentence, I usually did not say exactly what I intended.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you could say something like

*(By using this scheme, we ensure that) provided some devices are in idle mode, no device in the network will become overloaded.*

If I haven't understood, please make it clearer what you mean.